# How to get duplicate rows based on a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have  a data frame which has two columns 'Place' and 'Visits'. I want only those rows for which has same 'Place' values. For example if the data frame is like this:

```
Place  Visits
China     23
China     48
London    234
Paris     34
Boston    534
Boston    34
```

I want these rows only after the operation:

```
Place  Visits
China     23
China     48
Boston    534
Boston    34
```

How can I accomplish this in R? I tried using duplicated but it is not giving me the correct results.

Comment: How did you use `duplicated` and what did it return? Did you read `help("duplicated")` carefully?

Comment: I used `duplicated` like this:
`df[duplicated(df),]`

Comment: Assuming `dat` is your data.frame, you could use: `dat[dat[,1] %in% unique(dat[,1][ duplicated(dat[,1])]),]`

Comment: As the answer in the duplicate question tells, you can use `df[duplicated(df$Place) | duplicated(df$Place, fromLast = TRUE), ]`